# React - Automatic SlideShow

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do a React automatic slideshow (Im using node as server side) that starts automatic the slideshow after page loading/render.
At this point I only be able to insert a button and start the slideshow after clicking them.
I want to avoid the click user action and automatic start the slideshow after x seconds. 
I try to calling tick function on componentDidMounted and does not work.
Can any one help?

$SlidesShow.js >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```
import React from 'react';

import SlidesShowStore   from '../stores/SlidesShowStore';
import SlidesShowActions from '../actions/SlidesShowActions';
import Slides from '../components/Slides';

class SlidesShow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = SlidesShowStore.getState();
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.IMAGES = [];
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    SlidesShowStore.listen(this.onChange);
    this.tick();
    SlidesShowActions.startTimer();
    this.handleChange();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    SlidesShowStore.unlisten(this.onChange);
  }

  onChange(state) {
    this.setState(state);
  }

  handleChange() {
    this.setState(SlidesShowStore.getState());
  }

  toggleNext( event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var current = this.state.currentSlide;
    var next = current + 1;
    if (next > this.IMAGES.length - 1) {
      next = 0;
    }
    this.setState( {currentSlide: next} );
  }

  togglePrev(event) {
    event.preventDefault();   
    var current = this.state.currentSlide;
    var prev = current - 1;
    if (prev < 0) {
      prev = this.IMAGES.length - 1;
    }
    this.setState( {currentSlide: prev} );  
  }   

  toggleSlide(id) {
    var index = this.IMAGES.map(function (el) {
      return (
        el.id
      );
    });
    var currentIndex = index.indexOf(id);       
    this.setState( {currentSlide: currentIndex} );
  }

  Next() {
    var current = this.state.currentSlide;
    var next = current + 1;
    if (next > this.IMAGES.length - 1) {
      next = 0;
    }
    this.setState( {currentSlide: next} );
  }

  tick() {
    var self = this;
    this.interval = setTimeout(function() {
      if (self.state.status === 'stop') {
        self.interval = undefined;
        return;
      }
      if (self.state.timeLeft <= 0) {
        SlidesShowActions.timeout();
      } else {
        SlidesShowActions.tick();
        self.Next();
      }
      self.tick();
    }, 1000);
  }

  handleClickStart(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    this.tick();
    SlidesShowActions.startTimer();
    this.handleChange();
  }

  handleClickStop(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    SlidesShowActions.stopTimer();
    this.handleChange();
  }

  handleClickReset(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    SlidesShowActions.resetTimer();
  }

  render() {
    this.IMAGES = [
     {id: "slide1", imagePath : "/img/img1.jpg", imageAlt : "Slide 1 Image", title : "Slide 1", subtitle : "Slide 1 Image SubTitle", text : "Slide 1 Image Text", action : "Slide 1 Image Action", actionHref : "href"  },
     {id: "slide2", imagePath : "/img/img2.jpg", imageAlt : "Slide 2 Image", title : "Slide 2", subtitle : "Slide 2 Image SubTitle", text : "Slide 2 Image Text", action : "Slide 2 Image Action", actionHref : "href"  },
     {id: "slide3", imagePath : "/img/img3.jpg", imageAlt : "Slide 3 Image", title : "Slide 3", subtitle : "Slide 3 Image SubTitle", text : "Slide 3 Image Text", action : "Slide 3 Image Action", actionHref : "href"  }
    ];

    var self = this;
    var paginationNodes = this.IMAGES.map(function (paginationNode, i) {
      var boundClick = self.toggleSlide.bind(self, paginationNode.id);
      return (
        <span className="pager" onClick={boundClick}>  key={paginationNode.Title}  </span>
      );
     });

   return (  
    <div className="container">
      <div className="slideshow">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
        <Slides data={this.IMAGES} currentSlide={this.state.currentSlide} />
        <div className="pagination">{paginationNodes}</div>
        <div className="toggle toggle--prev" onClick={this.togglePrev.bind(this)}>Prev</div>
        <div className="toggle toggle--next" onClick={this.toggleNext.bind(this)}>Next</div>    
        <button onClick={this.handleClickStart.bind(this)}>Start</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClickStop.bind(this)}>Stop</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClickReset.bind(this)}>Reset</button>   
       </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SlidesShow;
```

Comment: From [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding), the `class` won't automatically bind the react componet to `thisArg` for you, try add `.bind(this)` to `componentDidMount` and `tick`, or use arrow function.

Comment: As sugested I changed the code as above and dont work. $componentDidMount() {
    SlidesShowStore.listen(this.onChange);
 this.tick().bind(this);
 this.handleChange();
  }

Comment: You should write as `componentDidMount() {...codes...}.bind(this)` and `tick() {...code...}.bind(this)`

Comment: Gives-me a error ... i think because I'm using Alt as Flux ... Thanks

Comment: Do you use babel to compile the js? Whats the error it gives?

Comment: Yes I'm using babel ... the error below:  SyntaxError: $C:/MYWORK/REACT/app/components/SlidesShow.js: Unexpected token (20:3)
  18 |  this.tick().bind(this);
  19 |  this.handleChange();
> 20 |   }.bind(this);
     |    ^
  21 |
  22 |   componentWillUnmount() {
  23 |     SlidesShowStore.unlisten(this.onChange);
    at Parser.pp.raise (C:\MYWORK\REACT\node_modules\babel\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\location.js:24:13)

Comment: Sorry, not sure what cause the issue, after recheck the codes, it seems ok to me, somehow react is not easy to debug without having an actual instance to play :\, I'm afraid that I can't give some helpful advice.

Answer (score 0):

React have now removed auto-binding in classes when extending from `React.Component`

You should be able to bind the instance of `this` to your function `this.tick.bind(this);`

Comment: As sugested I changed the code as above and dont work. $componentDidMount() {
    SlidesShowStore.listen(this.onChange);
 this.tick().bind(this);
 this.handleChange();
  }